# Angular upgrade - Error: inject() must be called from an injection context at injectInjectorOnly

Tags: angular

I have an angular project structured like so:

Site1

- Module1
- Module2
- SharedModule <- NOT in a library, just a module

Site2

- Module3
- Module4
- SharedModule <- calls module in Main directly

I know this isn't ideal, but it's how it is.

The `package.json` files are exactly the same apart from the names of the application.

The project was started on Angular 8 and has always upgraded well, but going from 11 -> 12 I'm having issues:

Site1 builds fine and runs nicely. Site2 builds fine, but errors immediately on running with

> Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
> at injectInjectorOnly (core:4745)
> at Module.ɵɵinject (core:4755)
> at Object.RouterModule_Factory [as factory] (router:5999)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11438)
> at R3Injector.get (core.js:11257)
> at core.js:11295
> at Set.forEach ()
> at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:11295)
> at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:25325)
> at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:25379)

As Site1 works fine, I assume it must be something in calling that SharedModule?

I've tried adding `"preserveSymlinks": true,` to projects.$name.architect.build.options, but that doesn't work. I'm not using `npm link` as the other module isn't a library (I know it should have been set up that way, but it isn't).

I've spent at least 2 days trying to get this to work (obviously checking posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51485868/inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685286/inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-when-using-angular-library-in), but the answers there dont seem to work.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or at least how to debug it please?

Comment: Have you try to delete nodeModules and reinstall?

Comment: @Den - Yep. Deleted the whole project, cloned it back off the repo - still get that error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the benefit of searchers, following not getting a response here, I asked [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43482) to Angular themselves.

Here are the answers provided.

> You have two distinct workspace trees that import from each
> other. That is bound to suffer from duplicate @angular/core versions
> which confuses the runtime, resulting in the rather obscure runtime
> error you're seeing. You can workaround this using paths mappings, as
> explained in the library guide here (which also applies to your
> situation without libs). Not sure why it worked in earlier versions,
> it has always been prone to these kinds of issues.

and

> The cause is that the two separate workspaces both have their own
> @angular/core packages, and both end up in the bundled application.
> The Angular runtime keeps its state in top-level module variables that
> are private to that module, but having two occurrences of that module
> (from both instances of @angular/core) you run into situations where
> state is only initialized correctly in one instance, not the other. In
> this case the injection context is only available in the "primary"
> runtime, but the parts of the app that were bundled from the
> "secondary" library parts will depend on the "secondary" runtime
> state.

So basically, the structure is bad. It should have been done as a proper library project in the first place.

I've made a demo of how it should have been done [here](https://github.com/HockeyJustin/AngularLibraryAndConumerApp).

Comment: While this is interesting, I am still barred from progressing.  I think my issue is related, but my setup is quite different.  I will open new SO question....  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I know this is a relatively old question but yesterday I had a similar issue and my workspace was already correctly configured as the example that was posted in the answer, on top of that it took a lot of googling to find another solution so I thought it would be best to share it somewhere with more visibility.

My issue was that if I injected a service from my local library without other dependencies it worked fine but if I injected a service that had to inject other dependencies into itself I had the same error showed in the question. The cause was exactly the same (2 different instances of angular) but what solved it for me was this

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25813#issuecomment-584866010

> For me, `"@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ]` (one dot, not
> two in the path) was what I needed, in addition to my own other
> mappings for my libraries. This only applies when using TypeScript
> path mapping instead of linking to the libraries, as documented here.
> Also, I put it in the tsconfig.json, not tsconfig.app.json. Either
> worked.
>
> So the paths portion of my tsconfig.json file in my main Angular app
> is:
>
> ```
> {   ...,   "compilerOptions": {
>     ...,
>     "paths": {
>       "@angular/*": ["./node_modules/@angular/*"],
>       "mylib/*": ["../../location/of/my/lib/src/*"]
>     }   },   ... }
> ```

I added `"@angular/*": [ "./node_modules/@angular/*" ]` to my tsconfig.json and it worked.

Despite the fact the github issue was closed saying it was solved with the release of Ivy I had this issue with angular 12 while using ivy

Comment: Great, this helped me after a long search! I'd like to point out to others that this should be added to the tsconfig.json in the app, not the library folder.