angular 18 cli data grid plugin error NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context
I'm having issues with a number of Angular data grid plugins... I've tried Angular DataTables, PrimeNG, Ngx-Datatable, Ag-Grid, Mat-Table and Kendo UI...
Every package after setup I get the following error... with the error varying between the different packages at the line in bold.

Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such
as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a
function used with runInInjectionContext. Find more at
https://angular.dev/errors/NG0203
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1099:15)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1112:42)
at ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:11391:16)
at NodeInjectorFactory.DatatableComponent_Factory [as factory] (swimlane-ngx-datatable.mjs:7164:43)
at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:6061:44)
at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:12265:27)
at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:11661:5)
at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:24344:9)
at Module.ɵɵelement (core.mjs:24402:5)
at CustomersFraudListComponent_ngx_datatable_5_Template (customers-fraud-list.component.html:7:1)

EDIT:
below are some pieces to help recreate the error
tsconfig.json ... I've added a few things here I found on ngx's examples
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,

    "downlevelIteration": true, //added

    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node", /* changed from module*/
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",

    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ], //added

    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],

    "resolveJsonModule": true, //added

    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, //added
    "paths": { //added
      "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": [ "dist/swimlane/ngx-datatable" ],
      "@swimlane/ngx-datatable/*": [ "dist/swimlane/ngx-datatable/*" ]
    },


    /*"strict": true,*/
    //"noImplicitOverride": true,
    //"noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    //"noImplicitReturns": true,
    //"noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    //"skipLibCheck": true,
    //"useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true, //added
    "enableIvy": true, //added

    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,

    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

Angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "providersolutionangularcore.client": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:directive": {
          "standalone": false
        },
        "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
          "standalone": false
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/providersolutionangularcore.client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kB",
                  "maximumError": "1MB"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kB",
                  "maximumError": "4kB"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "providersolutionangularcore.client:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "providersolutionangularcore.client:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development",
          "options": {
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "public"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ],
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

app.Module.ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, provideHttpClient, withInterceptorsFromDi } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';

import { AuthGuard, JwtInterceptor } from './_helpers';

... //Components removed for brevity

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'customers-fraud-list', component: CustomersFraudListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptorsFromDi()
    ),
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

packages.json
{
  "name": "providersolutionangularcore.client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem\" --ssl-key \"%APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key\" --host=127.0.0.1",
    "start:default": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-cert \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem\" --ssl-key \"$HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key\" --host=127.0.0.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^18.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^18.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "jest-editor-support": "*",
    "run-script-os": "*",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^18.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^18.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}


I've added the tsconfig, angular.json and app.module to the ticket for repro purposes... also added packages.json

solved using information found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212072/angular-upgrade-error-inject-must-be-called-from-an-injection-context-at-in. It turns out the grids plugins have their own instances of @angular/core ... without setting paths properly in tsconfig only the primary angular/core would run properly
